# Getting numbers instead of text for approval on custom forms. Approved ( 16 ) , Completed ( 5 )

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am getting numbers instead of text - approval status instead of "Approved" I am getting the number 16 and for Review a 5 instead of Completed?
Odd that on the same site the edit forms all show a label on them.
Is there something toggled on this site I am not aware of or is it corrupt?
Would really appreciate to how to fix it. I have never seen that happen before.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow status are stored as ID. In SP UI it get translated properly using Enumerated values.

In your case you should do it using conditional statements

```
NotStarted = 0
FailedOnStart = 1
InProgress = 2
ErrorOccurred = 3
StoppedByUser = 4
Completed = 5
FailedOnStartRetrying = 6
ErrorOccurredRetrying = 7
ViewQueryOverflow = 8
Canceled = 15
Approved = 16
Rejected = 17
```

Comment: Amal thank you but how do I get it back so that it doesn't use the numbers by default? It didn't do that before. Is there a "switch"?

Comment: I think you should use conditional statements to do that..